# WorkboxPlugin -One of the glob patterns doesn't match any files. Please remove or fix

Tags: service-worker, workbox

Error: One of the glob patterns doesn't match any files. Please remove or fix the following:

```
{                                     
  "globDirectory": "C:\\public\\uiassets",                         
  "globPattern": "^.*?(app.js|app.css|vendor.js|commons.js).*$",                                                                   
  "globIgnores": [                                                                                                                 
    "node_modules/**/*"                                                                                                            
  ]                                                                                                                                
}
```

is it mandatory to have the files mentioned in globPattern in build folder .

Answer (score 0):

That error is expected whenever you specify a pattern that doesn't match anything. It's often due to a malformed glob pattern, which appears to be what's causing your issue.

You're using `^.?(app.js|app.css|vendor.js|commons.js).$` as your glob pattern, which kind of looks like a RegExp syntax. Glob patterns require a different syntax, though, which is described at https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer